# How to change the 'Home' category name prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, html, categories

I'm just started the Prestashopv1.6.1.6 and want to change the 'HOME' category name appeared on the Top-horizontal menu to other.

I googled much, but the topics were specific for old versions.

Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to modify the "home" category name from prestashop backend.

In menu **Catalog** > **Categories** (index.php?controller=AdminCategories) > click on main / root category (usually named home and **id_category=1**)

In the main category admin, click on edit button (index.php?controller=AdminCategories&updatecategory&id_category=1 if id category is 1), and the first field is **name**, where you can modify it.

Comment: Hi, @DannetStudio. Thank you for your answer. I tried you mentioned. And it is Root category. So I changed the id number to 2. And it is 'home' category.  **(index.php?controller=AdminCategories&updatecategory&id_category=2)**

Answer (score 1):

To edit the home category on PrestaShop go on the backend then `catalog -> categories`.

From this page you can simply click on the "edit" link beside "homepage".

[image]

You can then edit is name and other related configuration options. In fact is like any category.

[image]